# Notepad++ v6.3.2 backreference regex replace not working

Tags: regex, notepad++, backreference

I have seen the instructions on using $1 in order to backreference the replace, but it is not working for me. Example:

I search for

```
&lt;header
```

to replace with

```
$1 class="bold"
```

and instead of `&lt;header class="bold"` I get `$1 class="bold"`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you capture the match in group?

Answer (score 4):

You must understand that $n refer to the capturing group number n. Since you don't have capturing groups in your search pattern, the group number 1 doesn't exist:

You must use capturing parenthesis to define a group, example:

```
search:  (&lt;header)
replace: $1 class="bold"
```

Another example:

```
search:  (&lt;)(header)
replace: $1$2 class="bold"
```

Notice: `$0` refers to the whole match (without define any capturing group). Then you can write:

```
search:  &lt;header
replace: $0 class="bold"
```